# Postgres role loses superuser attribute automatically

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-10

I am running Postgres (10.3) on my Ubuntu (16.04.4 LTS) VPS. I have some apps communicating with this database via an ODBC connection. Somehow, the role 'postgres' lost its attribute 'Superuser' automatically, without my intervention. Obviously, this led to multiple problems..

At first, I thought the problems had something to do with the amount of open connections, as they were 97, and my max_connections was at 100, superuser_reserved_connections at 3 and postgres had 'Replication' attribute on (and 'Superuser' as well, before it lost it). Anyway, I killed some connections and re-added the 'Superuser' attribute, and everything worked as it should.

But now the 'Superuser' attribute is lost again, and I have no clue where this weird behavior is coming from.. (my open connection count is not even near 97)

Does anybody know what can cause this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: That is not PostgreSQL's doing, it must be something else. There is no connection to `max_connections`.

Comment: Unfortunately looks like event triggers do not check for ALTER RULE event (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/event-trigger-matrix.html). So looks like you cannot log it. What about some unauthorized access? Is it possible you have some weak password (like "postgres") and public access for postgres user allowed in pg_hba.conf?